# Error creating bean with name 'roleRepository' java spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, beancreationexception

**RoleRepository**

```
package com.jawad.api.repository;

import javax.management.relation.Role;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends CrudRepository<Role,Integer>{

}
```

**AppsController**

```
package com.jawad.api.controller;

import java.util.List;

import javax.management.relation.Role;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.jawad.api.repository.RoleRepository;

@RestController
public class AppsController {
    
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository rolerepository;
    
    @GetMapping("/getAllRoles")
    public List<Role> getAllRoles() {
        return (List<Role>) rolerepository.findAll();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/hi")
    public String hi(){
        return "hi";
    }
}
```

**PrepaidWebAppApplication**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PrepaidWebAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PrepaidWebAppApplication.class, args);
    }    
}
```

When I run my application I get an error and I cannot find a way to fix it:

```java
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class javax.management.relation.Role
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:101) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1827) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1265) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:334) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:624) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:612) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:51) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:36) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:898) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at com.jawad.api.PrepaidWebAppApplication.main(PrepaidWebAppApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class javax.management.relation.Role
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:582) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:75) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:229) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:179) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:162) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:72) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:309) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:212) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:244) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:169) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
```

When I moved the `PrepaidWebAppApplication.java` to the model folder containing 3 models (user, role, and institution) it works but then my get requests won't be recognized anymore. I get the error: `404 not found`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: could you please share your Role entity?

Comment: `import javax.management.relation.Role;` this is not your `Role` entity

Comment: Yes import for your Role entity is different

Comment: thank you a lot @Hülya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have imported the `Role` entity from `javax` package in your `RoleRepository` and `AppsController`. Import it from your project and it should work for you.

```
import javax.management.relation.Role;
```

Change above import to your project `Role` entity.

Comment: @jayzee, I have added the answer, so that other users know it's been answered and the answer is accepted, please accept the same.

Answer (score 1):

Some basic concept on `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`:

1. `stereotype` annotations like: 
   **A.  *@Component***. 
   **B.  *@Controller*** 
   **C.  *@Service*** 
   **D.  *@Repository*** 
   in spring must be concrete class.
2. Latest version of Spring boot has `@EnableJpaRepositories` auto enabled with dependency of `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.
3. `@EnableJpaRepository` is responsible of registration of interface implementation of `CrudRepository`, `JPARepository`, so on. Here we don't need to add `stereotype` annotations of `SpringFramework`.
4. For interface `CrudRepository`, `JPARepository` has its part of JPA So class which it refer must have JPA annotations like `@Entity`, `@Table` on concrete class.

**Now coming back to your problem statement**

For `import javax.management.relation.Role`:

1. `import javax.management.relation.Role` is a concrete class, i.e. not abstract class --> **Accepted**
2. `import javax.management.relation.Role` class doesn't have JPA annotation, So we can't use directly with `CrudRepository`, `JPARepository` ---> **Not Accepted**
3. `RoleRepository` should not have `stereotype` annotations.

**Solutions:**

1. Create a class similar to `import javax.management.relation.Role` with JPA annotation on it.
2. JPA Entity used in `CrudRepository`, `JPARepository` must have `@Id` field in it else you will encounter new exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

Please also cross check your entity class, I missed the below Id annotation, and the generated value annotation on primary key, due to which org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException occurred on the Repository.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```